# Importing from same folder in python failing

Tags: python, import

I have a folder: `locust_runner`. In it are two files: `locust_runner.py`, and `locust_maker.py`. In `locust_maker.py`, I want to import everything defined in `locust_runner`.

If I do:

`from .locust_runner import *`

there is no highlighting indicating that this is an error. However, if I run it, I get:

`SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

I have tried every other combination of `from locust_runner import locust_runner` and everything else I can think of, but nothing works. How can I get this to function?

Comment: Are you running `locust_maker.py` as your top-level script? If so, you can't do that. The directory that the script is in is never a package. (Or, if you force it to be a package by monkeying with `sys.path`, that's illegal, even if not checked by the interpreter, and causes a whole bunch of problems.)

Comment: if you're running the script where the folder `locust_runner` is located, use `from locust_runner import *`

Comment: The answer is (1) Change things so that you either run it as a module (e.g., `python -m locust.locust_maker` from the parent directory). (2) Change things so the module isn't run directly, but instead exports a `main` or `run` entry-point function, and you have a separate script (in the parent directory again) that does `from locust.locust_runner import main; main()`. (3) Change things the same as (2), but use `setuptools` to build the script for you when you run `setup.py`, so it works properly even if your code is installed instead of run out of the source tree.